# Passing user data to Callback function using glade

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am using glade to make my .ui files and then using `GtkBuilder` I am loading that whole .ui file in my C program, so all the widgets and stuff are created from the builder files itself.

Earlier I had been creating widgets only from the code itself, hence allowing me to pass any type of data to the Callback since the second argument is a `gpointer` variable and I could anytime create a pointer to a custom made structure and pass any type of data to the callbacks.

But now to connect to the signals I am just using this simple function :

```
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
```

where `builder` is a pointer to `GtkBuilder`.

This connects all the signals mentioned in glade file with those of function defined in the .c files without having any provision of passing user_data other than that of Widgets (which themselves can only be defined in glade.)

Can anybody tell me a solution so that I can pass any type of data to my callbacks. I don't want to leave glade since it saves lot of my time, hence I would not like to switch over to traditional way of creating widgets by code only.

An example using both g_connect_signal() and gtk_builder_connect_signals() would be helpful. In this case which one to call first to override signal connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `gtk_builder_get_object` to retrieve any widget created by Glade given the widget's name. Then you can connect the widget to the signals with the usual `g_connect_signal` API. The drawback is that you can no longer simply "mention" signals in the glade definition.

The other way is to also use `gtk_builder_get_object` to get the object, but to call `g_object_set_qdata` to associate the necessary user data with a `GQuark` key known to you. Your callback can then pick up the user data from the widget using `g_object_get_qdata` with the same key. This has the advantage that you would still be using `gtk_builder_connect_signals`.

Answer (score 1):

That NULL pointer you are passing in is **for** the user data pointer.

```
gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
                                      ^
here----------------------------------|
```

If you always have the same user data object then your problem is solved. If not you
will need some kind of data structure for the different user data pointers so that
each callback can find the correct one.